# Different behaviour of commands in a script and the on the command line

Tags: powershell

Why do I get different outputs if I execute the following two commands in script and on the command line?

```
ps
dir
```

Is there an automatic pipe behaviour?

Here is the output from the two commands (outputs shortened):

```
PS C:\Users\Robzzz> ps

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
    682      73    73040      62340   423     2,31   8464 iexplore
    424      15     6332       6024    62             884 svchost

PS C:\Users\Robzzz> dir

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d-r--        23.09.2013     09:24            Contacts
d-r--        03.12.2013     15:30            Desktop
```

Here is the output from the script (outputs shortened):

```
PS C:\Users\Robzzz> .\psdir.ps1

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
    682      73    73040      62340   423     2,31   8464 iexplore
    424      15     6332       6024    62             884 svchost

PSPath            : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\Robzzz\Contacts
PSParentPath      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\Robzzz
PSChildName       : Contacts
PSDrive           : C
PSProvider        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
PSIsContainer     : True
Name              : Contacts
Parent            : Robzzz
Exists            : True
Root              : C:\
FullName          : C:\Users\Robzzz\Contacts
Extension         : 
CreationTime      : 02.01.2012 09:38:38
CreationTimeUtc   : 02.01.2012 08:38:38
LastAccessTime    : 02.01.2012 09:38:38
LastAccessTimeUtc : 02.01.2012 08:38:38
LastWriteTime     : 23.09.2013 09:24:09
LastWriteTimeUtc  : 23.09.2013 07:24:09
Attributes        : ReadOnly, Directory
BaseName          : Contacts
Mode              : d-r--


PSPath            : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\Robzzz\Desktop
PSParentPath      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\Robzzz
PSChildName       : Desktop
PSDrive           : C
PSProvider        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
PSIsContainer     : True
Name              : Desktop
Parent            : Robzzz
Exists            : True
Root              : C:\
FullName          : C:\Users\Robzzz\Desktop
Extension         : 
CreationTime      : 02.01.2012 09:36:02
CreationTimeUtc   : 02.01.2012 08:36:02
LastAccessTime    : 03.12.2013 15:30:08
LastAccessTimeUtc : 03.12.2013 14:30:08
LastWriteTime     : 03.12.2013 15:30:08
LastWriteTimeUtc  : 03.12.2013 14:30:08
Attributes        : ReadOnly, Directory
BaseName          : Desktop
Mode              : d-r--
```

Comment: There shouldn't be a difference. It's hard to tell without looking at something, a sample result can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Shay's comment.  My first guess is that it might be the host trying to resolve different kinds of output in the same format.

Here's a good post which outlines the issue (if that's it).

http://tfl09.blogspot.com/2013/11/powershells-single-formatting-pipeline.html

edit:  Your updated output confirms that this is the issue.